# Does sketchflow have a layout container?

Tags: .net, expression-blend, sketchflow

All I see as a rectangle. What I'd like to do is have a panel and add
controls into it (buttons, textfields, etc.) and then when I move the
panel the controls move with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes you select all the objects, right click and go group into -> grid